# What does this 'apt-get remove' instruction do?

Tags: command-line, apt, kernel, sed

What does the following code do?

I found it on internet so I copied it and pasted it into terminal but when I installed a new kernel it only detects the old one.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge $(dpkg -l 'linux-image-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d')
```

Comment: The second part is a regular expression, defining how the file name should look but not exactly which file name it is. Is it installing a kernel that is your objective or is it finding out exactly what the command removes?

Comment: This code will _not install_ any kernel, but _remove_ them! I don't see what exactly this sed-command does, but it processes the output of  `dpkg -l 'linux-image-*'`, which lists all installed kernel packages and filters some of them out for deletion by `apt-get remove`.

Comment: A very good rule of thumb to live by: if you don't know what a code does, don't put that code into Terminal until someone who knows what it does tells you.  If you're trying to get the most up to date kernel, you may want to look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade instead of using a code you don't understand.

Comment: Old kernels sitting around on disk cause no trouble, except for taking up disk space, and making `update-grub` (package postinst) slower.  If you're worried that you didn't actually boot the kernel you were trying to upgrade to, then run `uname -a`, or even `dmesg | less`

Comment: "I found it on internet so I copied it and pasted it into terminal" NO NO NO NO NO. You'll end up doing horrible things by accident. Running code you don't understand results in *terrible* things like nuking your system, and puppies being kicked.

Comment: If you want to clean old kernels, use ubuntu-tweak, it has a Janitor inside to clean stale kernels and its safe.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's break the code one by one (for my system):

```
$ dpkg -l 'linux-image-*'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                          Version             Architecture        Description
+++-=============================-===================-===================-================================================================
un  linux-image-3.0               <none>              <none>              (no description available)
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic 3.13.0-32.57        amd64               Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-g 3.13.0-32.57        amd64               Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic           3.13.0.32.38        amd64               Generic Linux kernel image


$ dpkg -l 'linux-image-*' | sed '/^ii/!d'
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic                         3.13.0-32.57                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic                   3.13.0-32.57                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                                   3.13.0.32.38                                        amd64        Generic Linux kernel image


$ uname -r | sed 's/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/'
3.13.0-32



$ dpkg -l 'linux-image-*' | sed '/^ii/!d' | sed "/$(uname -r | sed 's/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/')/d"
ii  linux-image-generic                                   3.13.0.32.38                                        amd64        Generic Linux kernel image



$ dpkg -l 'linux-image-*' | sed '/^ii/!d' | sed "/$(uname -r | sed 's/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/')/d" | sed 's/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/'
linux-image-generic



$ dpkg -l 'linux-image-*' | sed '/^ii/!d' | sed "/$(uname -r | sed 's/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/')/d" | sed 's/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/' | sed '/[0-9]/!d'
## No output
```

So this would do nothing:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge $(dpkg -l 'linux-image-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d')
```

As you can see **it was very close to removing my current kernel meta package** `linux-image-generic 3.13.0.32.38  amd64 Generic Linux kernel image` (thanks to this last `sed '/[0-9]/!d'` line) , which is wrong.

In a nutshell, this piece of `sed` has several issues. You should avoid it to remove your older kernels.

**EDIT:**

I have already said that the `sed` command has issues. For the sake of extension i am going to remove the last two lines with the form that actually should be working in my current scenario.

The last two lines in a modified form:

```
sed -r 's/^[^ ]* *(([a-z]|-)*)(-[a-z]*) *(([0-9]|-)*)\..*/\1-\4\3/'
```

So:

```
$ dpkg -l 'linux-image-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | 
sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d' | 
sed -r 's/^[^ ]* *(([a-z]|-)*(-[a-z]*) *(([0-9]|\.|-)*)\..*/\1\-\4\3/'
```

Outpus:

```
linux-image-3.13.0.32-generic
```

Thats very dengerous!!

Now showing what this would do to my system, `--dry-run` ning the full `apt-get remove` command:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --dry-run $(dpkg -l 'linux-image-*' | 
sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d' | 
sed -r 's/^[^ ]* *(([a-z]|-)*)(-[a-z]*) *(([0-9]|\.|-)*)\..*/\1\-\4\3/')


Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic' for regex 'linux-image-3.13.0.32-generic'
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  linux-headers-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-generic linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic linux-image-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Remv linux-generic [3.13.0.32.38]
Remv linux-image-generic [3.13.0.32.38]
Remv linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic [3.13.0-32.57]
Remv linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic [3.13.0-32.57]
```

As you see it will remove all my current kernels, also note that this is just a simulation to match my current scenario and the original `sed` can be improved.

** Note that the actual code will work if do a `reboot` after kernel upgrade as [Oli already mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/a/610175/216503).

**EDIT2:**

Here is a simple yet robust script that will consider all situations and remove the actual older kernels:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
kernels=( $(grep -Po "^linux-image-[^-]+-[^-]+-generic\b" < <(dpkg --get-selections)) )
cur_rel=$(grep -Po ".*(?=-[a-z]*$)" < <(uname -r))

for kernel in "${kernels[@]}"; do
    ker_rel=$(grep -Po "[0-9].*(?=-[a-z]*)" <<< "$kernel")
    dpkg --compare-versions "$ker_rel" gt "$cur_rel" && { echo "Please Restart your computer first"; break; }
    dpkg --compare-versions "$ker_rel" lt "$cur_rel" && sudo apt-get remove "$kernel"
done
```

If you have any version that is newer than the current one this will give you a warning to restart you computer first. Also note that the older kernels are preserved due to a good reason which is if you somehow mess up your current kernel making your system unstable then you should be able to boot into any older kernel.

Comment: Um,  wait, *what?* You replace the original, working code with some other code that you think "actually should (!!) be there", observe that your "fixed" code is broken and would remove your current kernel, and thus conclude that the original code is "very dengerous!!"? WTF? -1.

Comment: There are certainly valid reasons to criticize the original code, as pointed out e.g. in Oli's answer, and I'm sure the sed code could be made more robust. But that fact remains that, under normal circumstances (e.g. you've rebooted after your last kernel upgrade), the original code works, whereas your modified version doesn't.

Comment: First of all you should not use the last word you have used..now, did you actually run the actual code? removing the `apt-get` part and what output did you get?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: well, i second with you in some points, i have modified the answer..

Comment: Why, yes, I *did* run your modified command (the version that doesn't crash due to a missing parenthesis after `(([a-z]|-)*`, that is) without the `apt-get` part before criticizing it. On my system, it outputs the following lines: `linux-image-3.13-`, `linux-image-3.13-`, `linux-image-extra-3.13-`, `linux-image-extra-3.13-`, `linux-image-3.13.0.49-generic`. Is that *really* what you intended? (Also, bonus points if you can figure out which kernels I actually have installed.)

Comment: Ps. Also, the version comparison in your latest code is potentially broken: it would consider, say, `3.13.0.49` to be greater than `3.14.0.1` (because 313049 > 31401) or even `3.130.4.8` (because 313049 > 313048). Use [one of these solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023830/bash-how-compare-two-strings-in-version-format) (preferably, `dpkg --compare-versions`) instead of your `tr` hack.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: oops..did not get enough time to check it thoroughly..anyway.. thanks..i have modified it.....

Comment: @heemayl If the script's output is redirected to an unwritable file (plausible, for a user removing packages to save space) or piped to a process that fails to read from the pipe, `echo "Please Restart your computer first"` would actually fail, and then the `break` statement (after `&&`) won't run and the loop continues. Since that appears unintended, I suggest putting the `echo` and `break` statements inside the body of an `if` construct. Or to maintain compactness, they could go in a block (`{` `;}`) separated by a `;` (rather than `&&`). [*Demonstration.*](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10944193/)

Comment: @EliahKagan: Uhhhh..thats right.. although the situations seem less likely to happen but definitely plausible..edited..thanks for noticing :)

Answer (score 12):

This is an effort to remove kernels that aren't the current one.

There are many bits of code out there that do something like this and **this is it not a good example**. It could easily remove newer-than-current kernels and therefore the meta-package that installs (`linux-generic` et al) if you had an upgrade and didn't reboot.

Comment: And this is not a good idea at all. Those older kernels are kept for reason, by default there are only 2 old and a current one.